# Problems with cUrl giving constant http code 0 => error 6

Tags: php, curl

Hello and foremost thank you for your minute!

I am having troubles with cURL. This seems to work perfect on my localhost but on my server it just doesn't send off requests. Each response of the error code is "Could not resolve host: ....the url im searching..."

I haven't found much documentation on similiar errors online and it seems not much have encountered this issue.

```
$ch = curl_init() or die("Error");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "www.google.com");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
if(!curl_exec( $ch ))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
}
curl_close( $ch );
```

-> Google was placed as a test reference. But all return alike. This same issue occurs regardless if I set peer to false.

Comment: What testing have you done? Is this run from the cli or web server? can you ping the host your trying to connect to? Have you checked the web server log?

Comment: I have tested on localhost and it works fine. I will try cli from my web server. However, I have been trying to ping and it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Nor does it work on google domain... the server is live which is odd. I have check the files and nothing seems to be wrong

Comment: @JasonK thank you for the fast reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

In my case, I had the server configurations files misconfigured.

I went to ./etc/resolv.cnf.
Here I added the nameservers properly.

Hope it helps someone else coming across this issue!